# Building Android project in Jenkins "requires Maven version 3.1.1"

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I'm building an Android project in Jenkins. Everything was fine until upgrading to the lastest plugin version, but now it fails with "requires Maven version 3.1.1". Fair enough, but Jenkins seems to be stuck on Maven 3.0.4, even though I'm using the latest version (currently 1.553) of Jenkins and all its plugins. How to I make it update to a more current release of Maven?

Building in Jenkins via android-maven-plugin, which as of version 3.8.0 requires Maven 3.1.1 or higher (see http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog). Of course it can be done manually, outside Jenkins. The question is how to get Jenkins to use a current Maven; it seems to come packaged with an older one, and I'm not familiar enough with it to see where/how to update.

Update: For anyone following my footsteps, note that upgrading Maven will break the Android build until android-maven-plugin is also updated; they go together.

Comment: It would help if you would link the plugin you are using for Android builds. Building Android does not require Maven, so it very strange that you get that error. Also, a full console log would be very useful

Comment: If you are using OSX, make sure you remove/recreate the system symlink to mvn, as it defaults to the system's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins does not come with Maven, but it **can** install it for you.

### To Update Maven version used by Jenkins

- Goto **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System**.
- Scroll down till you see **Maven** section (not Maven Configuration or Maven Project, those are different).
- Click **Add Maven** button.
- Leave **Name** as *default*.
- Checkmark **Install Automatically**.
- **Install from Apache** is the default installer option.
- Select the version you want installed.
  [image]

Besides "Install from Apache", you can also install it from a **zip** or by **executing a command line**. Just delete the apache installer and click **Add Installer** button to select another option.

I would suggest to run a dummy Maven project at least once to verify this gets installed.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins doesn't come with maven as far as I am aware of. You can specify a maven installation in the Jenkins settings. I usually use a reference to a symlink (debian) and let that symlink point to my "current" or preferred Maven version.

You can alternatively install a recent maven version via Jenkins in the Jenkins settings aswell. And on my Jenkins there is a 3.1.1 via apache available.